# R: ifelse statement to create new variable equal to value of second variable conditional on value of third variable

Tags: r

I'm trying to create a new variable (NPHOURS) the value of which will be the value of a second variable (HOURS) conditioned on the value of a third variable (PROD) being equal to "N", otherwise I want the value of (NPHOURS) to be "0".

Sample data:

```
samp<-structure(list(HOURS = c(4.05, 4.05, 3.95, 3.95, 1), PROD = structure(c(2L, 
1L, 2L, 1L, 1L), .Label = c("N ", "Y "), class = "factor"), NPHOURS = c("0", 
"0", "0", "0", "0")), .Names = c("HOURS", "PROD", "NPHOURS"), row.names = c(NA, 
5L), class = "data.frame")
```

The following ifelse statement only produces "0".

```
samp$NPHOURS <- ifelse(samp$PROD == "N", samp$HOURS, 0)
```

Can anyone assist?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
str(samp$PROD)
```

so...report blank after "N" ....

```
samp$NPHOURS <- ifelse(samp$PROD == "N ", samp$HOURS, 0)
```

Answer (score 0):

We can also do

```
i1 <- grep('N', samp$PROD)
samp$NPHOURS[i1] <- samp$HOURS[i1]
```